# How to find out if SSL/TLS is mandatory on a listener port of kafka broker?

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, aws-msk

This might be done by issuing openssl s_client -connect with -no_tls1_2 -no_tls1_1 -no_tls1 -no_ssl3 -no_ssl2 but the result seems inconclusive to me. The listener is configured with SASL/SCRAM authentication enabled, but I am not sure if Encrypt data in transit Between clients and brokers Plaintext Enabled MSK cluster setting applies to that listener or not. Another way would be to connect to it and use wireshark to investigate traffic, if data is actually encrypted or not. The fact that I do not need to specify explicitly truststore does not mean it cannot use default java truststore and actually perform one way ssl handshake, when I give it such client settings:

```
      security.protocol=SASL_SSL
      sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512
```

Right?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have found the answer:

[image]

Plaintext does not apply to the listener with SASL/SCRAM control method.